# 14.04 Missing login prompt after screensaver

Tags: 14.04, login

This question is a duplicate of [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2227976), although I am not the same person as that poster.  I hope that re-asking it will be productive because (a) it seems to be a pretty terrible 14.04 bug, worth addressing/escalating, and (b) I'm going to provide some additional details.

Additional details about my system:

-- System 76 laptop

-- Intel® Core™ i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4

-- Intel® Ivybridge Mobile

-- 64 bit

-- I recently installed 14.04 as a clean install, from disk (no "upgrading").

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly there...  Can you try booting with nomodeset in the kernal options?  Since this only happens every 10 or 20 times, I don't expect that you would see a difference for quite a while.

Comment: Do you mean `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and then insert ` nomodeset` before the closing quotation mark at the end of the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`?

Comment: yes, although I would use gksudo instead of sudo.  This did help on an hp pavillion I was running, which had a similar issue, although we could not even see the password box.

Comment: well shoot, i already tried `sudo ...` and after restarting now my laptop does not detect the second monitor.  now what!?

Comment: update:  the marked solution here (http://askubuntu.com/questions/490112/xubuntu-14-04-does-not-detect-second-monitor) solved my lack of a second monitor ... so it sounds like I can't use your proposed solution?

Comment: for the record, i have also tried `qksudo`; this may have worked for a while (not sure; the problem is intermittant) but then I once again lost access to my second monitor and had to undo this.